# Sickle-cell trait : Why is only one type of beta chain found in any one hemoglobin molecule?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, malaria

I was reading a textbook (iGenetics, 3rd edition page 71), and came across the following passage:

> Homozygous bS bS people make Hb-S, the defective hemoglobin, with two
>   normal a chains specified by wild-type a-globin genes and two
>   abnormal b chains specified by the mutant b-globin bS allele: these
>   people have sickle-cell anemia. Heterozygous bA bS people make both
>   Hb-A and Hb-S and have sickle-cell trait. **Because only one type of b
>   chain is found in any one hemoglobin molecule**, only two types of
>   hemoglobin molecules are possible—one with two normal b chains, the
>   other with two mutant b chains.

(Emphasis mine)

My question is: **Why is only one type of beta chain found in any one hemoglobin molecule?** Or is this statement simply false?

I did search biology SE for similar questions, and found [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/88227/why-is-sickle-cell-trait-expressed-in-half-of-all-cells-rather-than-all-cells-co), but it is phrased poorly and the only answer does not address my question.

Answer (score -1):

For one specific hemoglobin molecule, yes it's just one type of beta chain.  In the case of a heterozygote, this hemoglobin molecule could be expressing from the bS gene OR the normal beta gene.  Let's call it a 50/50 chance for each hemoglobin to be expressing bS.  Because RBCs have a ton of hemoglobin in them, this 50/50 or so expression of bS wouldn't be enough to cause RBC sickling and disease, and it also helps explain the heterozygote advantage vs malaria.

Comment: _"Let's call it a 50/50 chance for each hemoglobin to be expressing bS."_ What? Hemoglobin is a protein, not a cell , it doesn't "express" anything.
Each hemoglobin molecule has _two_ beta chains: the question is: why do we never find one normal and one bS chain in the same hemoglobin tetramer.